# How to display street names from OS StreetAny layer?

Tags: qgis, layers, fields-attributes, ordnance-survey

Using QGIS version 2.10.1-Pisa.  I have imported layers from an Ordnance Survey data set. I have a layer called 'Street any' which gives me the boundaries of the streets which I can see.  I can see from the attribute table for the layer that the street names are there. How do I get the street names visible please. Long time since I did this and completely forgotten most of the little I once knew :(

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you want to **label** your streets layer to show the street names. You can do this by *right-clicking the layer > Layer Properties > Labels*, then select the attribute field which contains the names:

[image: Road label]

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is correct, there was a change between 2.8 and 2.10 where you have to active the labeling of the layer first.